# WiFi DELL XPS 13 9360 keeps disconnecting with QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter

Tags: 16.04, wireless, dell, atheros, firmware

I have a dual boot (in insecure mode) DELL XPS 13 9360 with windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I loose my internet connection over WiFi in Ubuntu. It says I still have a WiFi connection, but when I try to load a web page it does not work. Upon reconnecting the WiFi it works again.

I haven't noticed any problems under Windows, but I also don't use it that often.

I get the following error messages:

```
$ dmesg | grep ath10k
[    4.205120] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.208595] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    4.451852] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:3a:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    4.452298] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[    4.452302] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[    6.685390] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 4 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[    6.685394] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    6.770465] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0 wlp58s0: renamed from wlan0
[   31.785831]  drbg ansi_cprng ctr ccm arc4 rfcomm ax88179_178a usbnet mii bnep hid_multitouch i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core dell_wmi dell_laptop dcdbas snd_hda_codec_hdmi dell_led nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic x86_pkg_temp_thermal coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hda_intel ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm aesni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul snd_seq glue_helper snd_seq_device ablk_helper ath10k_pci snd_timer cryptd ath10k_core ath mac80211 serio_raw snd soundcore cfg80211 uvcvideo rtsx_pci_ms videobuf2_vmalloc memstick videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core v4l2_common input_leds joydev videodev media btusb idma64 btrtl virt_dma mei_me mei shpchp
[  333.016018] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to stop wmi scan: -11
[  333.016023] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to stop scan: -11
[  333.016025] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
[  337.016326] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -11
[  341.016440] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -11
[  342.066875] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: firmware crashed! (uuid 62bfa4a8-1fa3-4e94-9aba-362b8e591c7b)
[  342.066947] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 4 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[  342.066964] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[  342.068995] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: firmware register dump:
[  342.069013] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [00]: 0x05030000 0x000015B3 0x009860FA 0x00955B31
[  342.069021] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [04]: 0x009860FA 0x00060730 0x00000004 0x0040E8A0
[  342.069027] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [08]: 0x00498110 0x00955A00 0x0000000B 0x00400000
[  342.069033] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [12]: 0x00000009 0x00000000 0x00952CD0 0x00952CE6
[  342.069039] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [16]: 0x00952CC4 0x0091080D 0x00000000 0x0091080D
[  342.069047] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [20]: 0x409860FA 0x0040E7E8 0x00000000 0x0041E0DC
[  342.069057] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [24]: 0x800B5A1D 0x0040E848 0x000FFFFF 0xC09860FA
[  342.069064] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [28]: 0x809B3230 0x0040E948 0x00000018 0x004313DC
[  342.069070] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [32]: 0x809B2992 0x0040E998 0x0040E9C0 0x00429548
[  342.069077] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [36]: 0x8091D252 0x0040E9B8 0x00000000 0x00000002
[  342.069083] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [40]: 0x809FF05D 0x0040EA68 0x0043A380 0x00429C10
[  342.069089] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [44]: 0x809FCFDB 0x0040EA88 0x0043A380 0x00000001
[  342.069096] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [48]: 0x80911210 0x0040EAD8 0x00000010 0x004041D0
[  342.069102] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [52]: 0x80911154 0x0040EB28 0x00400000 0x00000000
[  342.069109] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [56]: 0x8091122D 0x0040EB48 0x00000000 0x00400600
[  342.069203] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -108
[  344.512357] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: device successfully recovered
[ 2346.814762]  drbg ansi_cprng ctr ccm arc4 rfcomm ax88179_178a usbnet mii bnep hid_multitouch i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core dell_wmi dell_laptop dcdbas snd_hda_codec_hdmi dell_led nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic x86_pkg_temp_thermal coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hda_intel ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm aesni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul snd_seq glue_helper snd_seq_device ablk_helper ath10k_pci snd_timer cryptd ath10k_core ath mac80211 serio_raw snd soundcore cfg80211 uvcvideo rtsx_pci_ms videobuf2_vmalloc memstick videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core v4l2_common input_leds joydev videodev media btusb idma64 btrtl virt_dma mei_me mei shpchp
[ 4457.132991] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to stop wmi scan: -11
[ 4457.132998] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to stop scan: -11
[ 4457.133002] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
[ 4461.133068] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -11
[ 4465.133108] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -11
[ 4466.258813] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: firmware crashed! (uuid 04fb9fb0-095b-4470-8de4-7228e15e1861)
[ 4466.258832] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 4 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[ 4466.258836] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[ 4466.260838] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: firmware register dump:
[ 4466.260845] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [00]: 0x05030000 0x000015B3 0x009860FA 0x00955B31
[ 4466.260848] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [04]: 0x009860FA 0x00060730 0x00000004 0x0040E8A0
[ 4466.260855] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [08]: 0x00498110 0x00955A00 0x0000000B 0x00400000
[ 4466.260857] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [12]: 0x00000009 0x00000000 0x00952CD0 0x00952CE6
[ 4466.260859] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [16]: 0x00952CC4 0x00910712 0x00000000 0x0091080D
[ 4466.260861] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [20]: 0x409860FA 0x0040E7E8 0x00000000 0x0041E0DC
[ 4466.260863] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [24]: 0x800B5A1D 0x0040E848 0x000FFFFF 0xC09860FA
[ 4466.260864] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [28]: 0x809B3230 0x0040E948 0x00000018 0x004313DC
[ 4466.260866] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [32]: 0x809B2992 0x0040E998 0x0040E9C0 0x00429548
[ 4466.260869] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [36]: 0x8091D252 0x0040E9B8 0x00000000 0x00000002
[ 4466.260873] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [40]: 0x809FF05D 0x0040EA68 0x0043A380 0x00429C10
[ 4466.260877] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [44]: 0x809FCFDB 0x0040EA88 0x0043A380 0x00000001
[ 4466.260881] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [48]: 0x80911210 0x0040EAD8 0x00000010 0x004041D0
[ 4466.260883] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [52]: 0x80911154 0x0040EB28 0x00400000 0x00000000
[ 4466.260885] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: [56]: 0x8091122D 0x0040EB48 0x00000000 0x00400600
[ 4466.260928] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -108
[ 4468.699722] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: device successfully recovered
```

I've tried reinstalling the drivers from the hw3.0 folder from [here](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6174).

Also you can find the wireless-info log [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23778255/), taken just after another crash.

Comment: @M.Becerra that info is in the full log. I'll rename it for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I fixed it. The problem probably originated from my router settings. When I changed from 802.11n+g+b to 802.11n+g the connection seems stable. Although over time I changed quite a lot of setting in Ubuntu and my router, this seemed to do the trick.

---

Edit 1/7/17:
Later I found another crucial option which I had to *uncheck* in order to get it to work. In my Fritzbox router it is called:

> Wireless LAN coexistence enabled
>
> In heavily used wireless environments the available channel width is divided among the participants in the best way possible.

I think this option sometimes changes the bandwidth of the signal. When this happens the connection is lost between my laptop and the router. In the `/var/log/syslog` file I also saw something like: `bandwidth changed, connection lost`, if I recall correctly.

Comment: I also see the bandwidth message before it "crashes", though the Wifi didn't really disconnect, the DNS doesn't work anymore (totally locks up), I have to disconnect/reconnect or restart network manager to fix.

Log: `xps13 kernel: [...] wlp58s0: AP xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx changed bandwidth, new config is 2462 MHz, width 1 (2462/0 MHz)`

Comment: I'll try this later. Even if it fixes the problem, the driver still should be able to handle that. If this turns out to be the cause I'll report it upstream (if it's not reported yet).

Comment: I have the exact same problem, but I don't see the bandwidth change. Rather, I see it trying to establish which country code it should use or something like that.

Comment: I found out it's related to group rekeying, not to bandwidth changing, as in https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=879184

Answer (score 4):

I would disable wifi power management with

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Change the encryption on the wireless router to WPA2 only with no WEP, TKIP or plain WPA, depending on the router it may be called WPA2-PSK, WPA2-AES or WPA2 Personal.

Reinstall the linux-firmware package

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

Reboot

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes. Lets see if it works. WPA2 was called WPA2 (CCMP) in my router btw.

Comment: This did not solve the problem unfortunately.  I also tried to set my router to a fixed channel, but this also did not work

Comment: You have some other issues if you look at the errors at 2346.814762 that shows some module names, that usually means there is a serious error with something else and that may be affecting wifi to some extent

Comment: Any way to find out which one is causing the trouble?

Comment: You would likely have to look through the syslog in /var/log to see if there is  a stack trace or other errors

Comment: I find this error in the syslog: `Jan 17 09:49:56 roald-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 6206.032565] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915_bpo]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=198476 end=198477) time 162 us, min 894, max 899, scanline start 892, end 901`. Is it relevant? And how can I fix it?

Comment: That is something for a new question as it appears to be an issue with Intel video

Comment: Reconfigure my router to WPA2-AES fixed this issue for me as well on Lenovo Thinkpad E470. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can try removing and re-adding kernel module of your wifi driver

```
lsmod |grep wifi
```

in my machine I got the following:

```
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
```

then:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Comment: When I do  `lsmod |grep wifi` I get no result.

Comment: can you try `lsmod |grep iwlmvm`   if you got results, can you then try  `sudo modprobe -r iwlmvm && sudo  modprobe iwlmvm`. if no please try `lsmod |more` without `grep` so you can search the whole results for the available wireless network driver then do `sudo modprobe -r <drivername> && sudo modprobe <drivername>` .

Comment: Do you mean ath10k_core and ath10k_pci?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with this wifi card on Debian. Updating settings on router wasn't an option. What helped was to update binary firmware from here: https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4.1

Just download last version and replace file `firmware-6.bin` located at `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/`.

Then reload affected kernel modules:

```
modprobe -r ath10k_pci ath10k_core
modprobe ath10k_pci
modprobe ath10k_core
```

Comment: will this also work for ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, it does. It also works for other linux distros as well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried new firmwares and many other different solutions with no avail on Ubuntu 20.10. Firmware crashes and disconnecting still kept happening.

Finally, I wrote following bash script which I run on startup. It will automatically reconnect to AP when connection is lost. Maybe it will help you too.

You might need to install fping utlity

`sudo apt install fping`

Edit name of your WLAN interface on line 2 and run script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
interface=wlp58s0;
ping_interval=5

while /bin/true; do
    connect=`iwconfig $interface | grep ESSID:off`
    if [ "${connect}" ]; then
            echo "Connect to some AP first.";
            sleep 10;
    else
            startdate=`date`;
            ip=`ip route show 0.0.0.0/0 dev $interface | cut -d\  -f3`
            reconnect=0
            essid=`iwgetid $interface -r`
            
            echo -e "Monitoring WLAN connection \n WLAN interface: $interface \n ESSID: $essid \n Default gateway: $ip \n Ping interval: $ping_interval s"

            while /bin/true; do
            up=`fping -r 1 $ip | grep alive`
            connect=`iwconfig $interface | grep ESSID:off`
            if [ -z "${up}" ] && [ -z "${connect}" ]; then
                    echo "Warning: connection lost at $(date)"
                    ((reconnect=$reconnect+1))
                    echo "Reconnecting..." &&
                    nmcli dev connect $interface &&
                    echo "Done! Connection on at $(date)"
                    echo -e "Reconnected $reconnect times from $startdate. \n"
            fi
            sleep $ping_interval
            done
    fi
done
```