# Intel video error: Atomic update failure on pipe A

Tags: graphics, intel

I was having problems with my wifi connection on my Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 16.04 and asked a question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870412/wifi-dell-xps-13-9360-keeps-disconnecting-with-qca6174-802-11ac-wireless-network) about it. During the diagnoses I came across the following error found in /var/log/syslog:

```
Jan 17 09:49:56 roald-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 6206.032565] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915_bpo]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=198476 end=198477) time 162 us, min 894, max 899, scanline start 892, end 901
```

I've tried to google it, but I did not find a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1660619